# Text wrap in multicols

Tags: tables, multicol, wrap

The following LaTex code ([credit](http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/)) features a table within `muticols`:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
...
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \subsubsection{Another Subsubsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
      \verb!Lorem!   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
      \verb!ipsum!   & consectetur adipisicing elit\\
      \verb!dolor!   & sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua\\
      \verb!sit!     & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
      \verb!amet!    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{multicols}
```

The `Lorem ipsum` before the table is properly wrapped, but the long line (`sed ipsum...`)   inside the table isn't.

Is there a way to force wrapping on all column contents? If not, which table property should be changed to assure wrapping?

Comment: `l` columns are always single line, use `p{5cm}` to make a fixed width column in which text wraps.

Comment: Where should I put the `p` in my example?

Comment: change `@{}ll@{}` to `@{}lp{5cm}@{}` note this is nothing to do with multicols it is standard latex tabular usage so any latex guide or the questions linked on the right should help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be interested in the `tabularx` environment that allows for "wrapped contents" within an `X` column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\section{Another Subsubsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
  \texttt{Lorem}   & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
  \texttt{ipsum}   & consectetur adipisicing elit \\
  \texttt{dolor}   & sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \\
  \texttt{sit}     & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
  \texttt{amet}    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{tabularx}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

You have to specify the width over which the `tabularx` should span (`\linewidth` in this case), the `X`-columns fill to that width in a paragraph style.